# How to bevel across the faces of a cylinder or curve

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I beveled the single face towards the bottom right, now I want to do the same to the selected area. From what I've gathered, you cannot bevel across multiple faces. I want to bevel this area, while also keeping its curvature; is there any way I can do that? I've just started, so I can do something that involves restarting the project. I'm also doing this across the whole cylinder so if there's any faster way than manually doing it, then that would be appreciated, but not required. Thank you all!

[image: The cylinder I'm trying to bevel along the faces of]

Comment: No you can't bevel the vertex like you did on the bottom right, but maybe show the reference object that you're trying to model so that we propose another way?

Comment: @moonboots I'm so sorry! Does this help? [Image 1](https://imgur.com/kQdiant) [Image 2](https://imgur.com/0fOYIFV) Right now, it looks like how it does in the second image, when I would like it to look like how it does in the first. If I tried to bevel it, it would create a flat ngon, like this: [Image 3](https://imgur.com/fRRPAfC) when I want it to follow the cylinder's original curvature.

Comment: You could try something like that, not very elegant but it will probably not create any bad shading: https://www.zupimages.net/up/24/06/78bk.jpg

Comment: Actually you should tell a bit more about the object you're trying to achieve, does it need to be high-poly, can you use a Subdivision Surface, etc?

Comment: I don't know what I'm confined to like what you're asking. So I think whatever works, works, I'm willing to try everything out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *Knife Project* tool: Create your cylinder, create another object that is a circle, put it in front of the cylinder, select the cylinder, switch to *Edit* mode, select the circle with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>, go into *Mesh > Knife Project*, it will cut a circular edge loop on the cylinder:

[image]

create an horizontal edge loop with the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut orthogonally, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through:

[image]

Clean the topology (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to dissolve vertices):

[image]

Remove faces:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for working with me on this! Your answer works just as expected, even when I couldn't provide a detailed answer to your questions. Thank you for all the hard work you put into strengthening the blender community!

Comment: you're welcome   ;)